# Calculation of Inputted Values When Radio Buttons Are Clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble to calculate my inputs even when I edit the default inputs. I want all the inputs to sum up when the user clicks on the selected 'Yes' radio buttons and then clicks on the 'Calculate' button in order to get the sum of inputted values. Need help on the code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

function findTotal()
{
    var arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
    var tot=0;
 var stdHour=0;
 
 
 for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) //i=1/i=0
 {
  var radios = document.getElementsByName('group'+i);
  
  for(var j = 0; j < radios.length; j++) 
  {
   var radio = radios[j];
   
   if(radio.value == "Yes" && radio.checked) 
   {
    if(parseInt(arr[i].value))
    {
     tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
    }
   }
   
  }
  
 }
  
  document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
  document.getElementById('stdHour').value = 3600/tot;
    
}
</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

<!--Table designing-->
table 
{
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%%;
 align: center;
}
td, th 
{
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) 
{
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
input
{
   text-align:center;
}

</style>
</head>
<!--Start of Table Developing-->


<body>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>

<form id="radioForm" method="get" >

<table style="width:70%" align="center">


<!--Attributes of table. Colspan used to insert sub-title for the main title.-->
  <tr>
    <th>Test Points</th>
    <th colspan="4">Cycle-Time</th>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>Edit</td>
    <td>Yes</td>
    <td>No</td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <label id="group1"> <!--label is used to control the respective group of radio buttons-->
    <td>Initial (On Arrival)</td>
 <!--The input box in the 'Edit' column is set as below-->
    <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="20" align="center" name="qty" id="qty1" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <!--The check boxes of 'Yes' and 'No' is created as below-->
    <td><input type="radio" name="group1" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group1" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
 
  <tr>
  <label id="group2">
    <td>Drop Test (Portable Only)</td>
    <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty2" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group2" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group2" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <label id="group3">
    <td>Power Up Test (Mobile Only)</td>
    <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty3" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group3" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group3" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <label id="group4">
    <td>User Interface Room</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty4" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group4" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group4" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><B>-30 Degree C (Cold Temp)</B></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <label id="group5">
    <td>ATE Labview RF Testing Extreme</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty5" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group5" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group5" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <label id="group6">
    <td>User Interface Extreme</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty6" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group6" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group6" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <label id="group7">
    <td>Mic Talk Internal Extreme</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty7" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group7" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group7" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <label id="group8">
    <td>Mic Talk External Extreme</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty8" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group8" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group8" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <label id="group9">
    <td>Desense Test</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty9" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group9" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group9" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <label id="group10">
    <td>Tx Stability</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty10" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group10" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group10" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <label id="group11">
    <td>Microphonic Test</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty11" maxlength="10" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group11" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group11" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><B>+60 Degree C (Hot Temp)</B></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <label id="group12">
    <td>ATE Labview RF Testing Extreme</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty12" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group12" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group12" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <label id="group13">
    <td>User Interface Extreme</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty13" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group13" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group13" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <label id="group14">
    <td>Mic Talk Internal Extreme</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty14" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group14" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group14" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <label id="group15">
    <td>Mic Talk External Extreme</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty15" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group15" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group15" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <label id="group16">
    <td>Desense Test</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty16" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group16" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group16" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <label id="group17">
    <td>Tx Stability</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty17" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group17" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group17" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <label id="group18">
    <td>Microphonic Test</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty18" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group18" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group18" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td><B>Final (Ambient Room Temp)</B></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <label id="group19">
    <td>Drop Test (Portable Only)</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty19" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group19" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group19" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <label id="group20">
    <td>ATE Labview RF Testing Room</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty20" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group20" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group20" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <label id="group21">
    <td>Mic Talk Internal Room</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty21" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group21" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group21" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <label id="group22">
    <td>Mic Talk External Room</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty22" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group22" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group22" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <label id="group23">
    <td>Final Mechanical Inspection</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty23" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group23" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group23" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <label id="group24">
    <td>Label Info Verification</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty24" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group24" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group24" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <label id="group25">
    <td>Gauge Checking</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty25" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group25" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group25" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <label id="group26">
    <td>Charging</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty26" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group26" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group26" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
  <label id="group27">
    <td>Packaging Buy Off</td>
 <td><input onblur="findTotal()" type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty27" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group27" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group27" value="No"></td>
  </label>
  </tr>
  
 
  <tr>
 <td>Total (seconds)</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="total" id="total"/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
 <td>Standard Hour</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="stdHour" id="stdHour"/></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
 <td>VCT Capacity</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="capacity" id="capacity"/></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
 <td>Head Count</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="hc" id="hc"/></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
 <td>Number of Days</td>
 <td><input type="text" name="days" id="days"/></td>
  </tr>

</table>

<button type="button" align="center" onClick="findTotal()">Calculate</button>

</form> <!--End of Form-->
```

Comment: write your code in snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your quantity count does not match as you have group names starting from 1 (e.g `group1`). Just modify this line, and it should work.

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName("group" + (i+1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have removed quite a bit of HTML but it works: the code is below. You can just add the other sections in it will work.

I have started the count at `0`: so the first section has `group0` and `qt0`, it helps a lot when going through the arrays in the JS code. Also, I have removed all the `.onblur` calls, only the button click will run `findTotal()`.

```js
function findTotal() {
  let arr = document.getElementsByName('qty');
  let tot = 0;
  let stdHour = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    let radios = document.getElementsByName('group' + i);

    for (let j = 0; j < radios.length; j++) {
      let radio = radios[j];

      if (radio.value == "Yes" && radio.checked) {
        tot += parseInt(arr[i].value);
      }

    }

  }

  document.getElementById('total').value = tot;
  document.getElementById('stdHour').value = 3600 / tot;

}
```

```css
table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%%;
  text-align: center;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

input {
  text-align: center;
}

#button {
  width: 200px margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<form id="radioForm" method="get">

  <table style="width:70%" align="center">

    <tr>
      <th>Test Points</th>
      <th colspan="4">Cycle-Time</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Edit</td>
      <td>Yes</td>
      <td>No</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <label id="group0">
    <td>Initial (On Arrival)</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="20" align="center" name="qty" id="qty0" maxlength="4" size="4"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group0" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group0" value="No"></td>
  </label>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <label id="group1">
    <td>Drop Test (Portable Only)</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty1" maxlength="4" size="4"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group1" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group1" value="No"></td>
  </label>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <label id="group2">
    <td>Power Up Test (Mobile Only)</td>
    <td><input type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty2" maxlength="4" size="4"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group2" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group2" value="No"></td>
  </label>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <label id="group3">
    <td>User Interface Room</td>
 <td><input type="text" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty3" maxlength="4" size="4"></td>
 <td><input type="radio" name="group3" value="Yes"></td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="group3" value="No"></td>
  </label>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Total (seconds)</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="total" id="total" /></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Standard Hour</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="stdHour" id="stdHour" /></td>
    </tr>

  </table>

</form>

<div id="button"><button type="button" align="center" onClick="findTotal()">Calculate</button></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so so much,man. It resolved the issue and also so sorry for the bad question format & thanks a bunch for correcting me.